# Prevent a TeamCity build configuration to run for certain branches

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-2019

Is there a way to configure a build configuration in a way that it may run only for certain branches. I'm not only talking about automatic triggers, I also want to prevent users from manually triggering a run for other branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the version control settings for a build configuration you can add [branch filters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/branch-filter.html#BranchFilter-BranchFilterFormat):

[image: branch filters]

Answer (score 0):

To prevent users from manually triggering a build, you need to set user permissions. This can be done under `Administration > users/groups > group name/username > roles`.

If you want them to only view the project, you can assign the role *Project Viewer*.
You can also make your own roles with your own set of rules by clicking `Administration > roles`.

Comment: Actually, manually triggering is also prefvented by infojolt's answer.

Comment: Not necessarily, say for example you have two parameters being passed to your vcs root: the %vcs.git.branch.default% and the %vcs.git.branch.pattern%. You can then specify which branch you want to build off by changing those parameters. Granted, if you set the branch filter to exclude certain branches, the build will fail, but the build will still kick off.